# Can't return to command line

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Total noob question - it has me stumped.  I'm using SOX to create spectrograms of images files, and it's been working fine, but now when I try to execute it just gives me a carat prompt and does nothing (>)...anything I type seems to have no effect.  Command-. does get me back to the normal prompt.  Here's what it looks like on my screen:

```
    Last login: Tue Oct 24 11:39:33 on ttys000
    Scotts-iMac:~ scottwhittle$ cd /Users/scottwhittle/Desktop/Belize\Test2 
    Scotts-iMac:Belize Test2 scottwhittle$ for file in *.mp3
    > do
    >     outfile="${file%.*}.png"
    >     sox "$file" -n spectrogram r -l -m -d "$title_in_pic" -o ”$outfile" -X 5000 -y 513 norm
    > done
    > help!
    > nothing I type seems to do anything
    >
```

What's confusing is that it works sometimes and not others.  One thing I am doing is editing the command in TextEdit to change parameters, and then copying and pasting to terminal.  Is thing the issue?  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: You have a "curly" quote before the `$outfile`... I bet that's what's messing with you ;)

Comment: Oh - and you can probably hit `CTRL+C` to get back to the normal prompt. (I'm guessing that would be `CMD+C` on a MAC, but I don't own one, so what do I know)

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much - I wouldn't have every caught that

Comment: @Mikk3lRo: I'm pretty sure it's Ctrl-C on Mac.